# If statement returning last condition

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I've been doing some work playing around with R shiny. I'm pretty new to R and this could be a simple syntax error.

The following code belows to my server.r and the renderText(mx()) seems to only return the output of the last chronological if statement. (When I swap them around, it changes accordingly). The input$numbers is a text input which I change to a list, and the input$mean_type corresponds to a radio button which has the following options

```
radioButtons('mean_type', 'Which operation?',
c('Arithmetic Mean' = 'A', 'Geometric Mean' = 'G', 'Variance' = 'V'))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

```
mx <- reactive({
            x <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(input$numbers,",")))
            if (input$mean_type == 'A') {
                mean(x)
            }
            
            if (input$mean_type == 'V') {
                sd(x)
            }
            
            if (input$mean_type == 'G') {
                geometric.mean(x)
            }
        })
output$mean <- renderText(mx())
```

Comment: In the absence of a `return` in the body of the expression passed to `reactive()`, it's the value of the last evaluated expression that is returned, i.e. `geometric.mean(x)` if the last condition evaluates to `TRUE`, or `NULL` otherwise. A solution could be adding `return`s in each `if` block, or going the `if`-`else` route

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `else if` instead of `if` in the subsequent statements — otherwise, your  subsequent `if` statements have an implicit `else NULL` branch attached; that is,

```
if (a) A
if (b) B
```

is really the same as

```
if (a) A else NULL
if (b) B else NULL
```

And the value of a sequence of statements in R is the value of the *last expression* in that sequence.

So your code should look as follows:

```
mx <- reactive({
    x <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(input$numbers,",")))
    if (input$mean_type == 'A') {
        mean(x)
    } else if (input$mean_type == 'V') {
        sd(x)
    } else if (input$mean_type == 'G') {
        geometric.mean(x)
    }
})
```

Alternatively, you could use early exit; that is, use `return(mean(x))` instead of `mean(x)`, etc. However, I prefer the above solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly! The syntax is not like python in that sense.

Comment: @Ben Yes, Python works fundamentally different from R in this regard, because in R every expression has a value. In Python this isn’t the case, and you *always* need to explicitly use `return` if you want to return a value.